# Limit daily page views?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, pageviews

I would like to limit daily page views in my WordPress website.
If it can be done by IP, would be best.
Also, if can't, can it be done globaly, for whole website.
Like, lets say 100 page views, and site will go offline until new day.
Any php script that can be implemented to do this?
Or maybe by htaccess?

This is not asked/answered anywhere, but I need this.
Few similar questions and answers goes on that I or anyone who want this should change hosting provider.

Comment: You could track the IP in a table in the db. Each time a page is viewed at that IP, increment a field in the db. When it hits your magic number of 100, instead of returning the requested page, send them away.

Comment: You'd want to be sure to flush the fields now and then too.

Comment: It seems like there must be more necessary information here. Why would you want to allow someone to DDoS your site so easily?

Comment: @Ed Cottrell, I have non profit website on hosting from my internet provider. Also I have domain from them. I use website to post videos and similar funny things, just a hobby when I am bored. Every day I am getting more views now, and I want to limit that somehow. I am paying big bills for exceeded monthly bandwidth of 5GB.

Comment: Jeez the company doesn't cut you off? Just keeps charging???

Comment: @Chitowns24, unfortunatelly, yes, they charging me about 1.00usd for 1.00GB exceeded bandwidth. 5.00GB can be only 5 days for me now.

Comment: Kindof as a side thought, nothing really to do with your main problem but do you host the videos on your site? or like YouTube?

Comment: @Chitowns24, no, not self hosted. I am embeding videos. YouTube, Dailymotion, Vimeo etc. Still, one page is 5mb, caching also can't help than I exceed storage 200MB. :D Well, I know, this hosting is "hook for money", but if anyone could give me some code to limit it would be ok for me. I don't need to have website that will be something special and always avaible.

Comment: Use a content delivery network.

Comment: You might want to check out [cloudflare.com](http://cloudflare.com), a free CDN.